# How to write limit exactly below the lim?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write the written below the lim as shown in figure

[image]

But what I tried is `$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}$`

How to write it exactly as shown in the figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of limits for operators is dependent on whether you're in display math or in-line math. The simplest thing is to write, e.g.,

```
\[
  \lim_{(x,y)\to(x_{0},y_{0})} f(x, y) =
  \lim_{(x,y)\to(2,4)}  (x^{2}+y^{2}-3 = 4-16-3 = 17
\]
```

(I fixed an error in the mathematics when I typed the LaTeX code. lim on its own is meaningless, the second = should not be there.)

The subscripts on this are going to be wider than the lim, so by default they'll stick out to either side of lim. To get the formatting as in the above equation, you'd need to add spacing manually on either side (it looks like `\quad` maybe).

**But I really want to do this in in-line math**. No, you probably don't but if you insist, you can add `\displaystyle` to your in-line math to get the subscript below `\lim` in the equation. The result will not look good though, and I would recommend against it.